# PsychoPy adding Spaces to TextStim

Tags: python, psychopy

```
        while True:
            #win.flip()
            keys = event.getKeys(keyList = ['space', 'return', 'backspace','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
            if any(key in keys for key in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']):
                textbox.text += keys[0]
            if 'return' in keys:
                break
            for key in keys:
                if key == 'backspace':  # Handle backspace
                    textbox.text = textbox.text[:-1]
                    textbox.draw()
                    print('backspace')
                elif key == 'space':
                    textbox.text += ' '
                    print(key)
                else:
                    if len(str(textbox.text)) % 75 == 0:
                        textbox.text += '\n'
                    else:
                        textbox.text = textbox.text[:-1]
                        textbox.text += key
                    print('input', textbox.text)
                    textbox.draw()
                welcome_stimuli[stimuli_order[i]].draw()
                win.flip()
```

Hi, I have a code that allows participants to input text into PsychoPy with the Keyboard in real time. It works well but when I want it to add spaces between the letters it adds a line break instead. I tried several ways of adding spaces but they all seem to just end up in line breaks and simulate \n. Does someone know how to add spaces to a visual TextStim?

Comment: May be to try code of the space ('\x20') to get around some built-in check?